# If statement to check if array is null or empty, doesn't work

Tags: java

I got my main task to work (rough translation):

> Write a method, which returns the smallest number from a 1d array of
>   integers.

Now i have to do a side task (rough translation):

> Add an if statement to check if the array is null or empty, and if it
>   is, return 0.

method:

```
public static int smallestNumber (int[] array1) {

    int smallest = array1[0];

    if (array1 == null || array1.length == -1) {
       return 0;
    }

    else {
       for (int element : array1) {
          if (element < smallest) {
           smallest = element;
          }
       }
    }
return smallest;    
}
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] tab1 = {}; //empty array?
  int smallestNumber = smallestNumber(tab1);
  System.out.printf("The smallest number is: %d", smallestNumber);
}
```

The method works if i only check for null. But i'm confused why it wont work on empty array.

`int[] tab1 = {};`

EDIT: I also tried with array1.length == 0;

Comment: Hi Captain, Why are you initializing an int[] with curly brackets? and not using new, for example `int[] intArray = new int[];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, Arrays are of non-negative size so `array1.length` cannot be -1, instead make the comparison with `0`.

Secondly, the assignment  `int smallest = array1[0];` tries to access 0th position of an empty array which will result in `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So in conclusion move the assignment to `smallest` in the else block and check the condition for empty or null array before you try to access any array value.

```
public static int smallestNumber (int[] array1) {

    int smallest;

    if (array1 == null || array1.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    else {
        smallest = array1[0];
        for (int element : array1) {
            if (element < smallest) {
                smallest = element;
            }
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
this is what i get when i do == 0

Comment: move the assignment for smallest below the condition

Comment: @CaptainApple now try this code, the line where you assigned the initial value of `smallest` was incorrect move it inside the `else` block and also change the comparison to -1.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int smallestNumber (int[] array1) {
    if (array1 == null || array1.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int smallest = array1[0];
    for (int element : array1) {
        if (element < smallest) {
            smallest = element;
        }
    }

    return smallest;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes wasnt sure if it was true or not but i went with == 0 first before becoming desperate to even try -1. Issue solved above

Comment: I updated my answer. First we need check `array1 == null || array1.length == 0` before array operation, ex: `array1[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for null first, as it is safer to check for that first. You also can use the method isEmpty() for the length.

```
public static int smallestNumber (int[] array1) {

if (array1 == null) {
    return 0;
}

if (array1.isEmpty()) {
    return 0;
}

   int smallest = array1[0];
   for (int element : array1) {
      if (element < smallest) {
           smallest = element;
      }
   }
    return smallest;
}
```

or add this as an alt:

```
public static int smallestNumber (int[] array1) {

if (array1 != null) {
    if (array1.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

  int smallest = array1[0];

  for (int element : array1) {
      if (element < smallest) {
           smallest = element;
      }
   }
      return smallest;

   } else {
     return 0;
    }
}
```